# Highcharts:Add image to legend

Tags: highcharts, legend

I have this chart. I want to add some check icons in the rectangle from the legend, when it is selected.
How can I do this?

```
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: this,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }

    },
    series: [{
        data: jsonChart
    }],
    legend: {
        symbolWidth: 40,
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 40,
        y:0,
        width: 150,

    },

});
```

});[The chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H0Ow.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer) to render an image in the chart.

```
  function drawTicks() {
    const {
      translateX: tx,
      translateY: ty
    } = this.legend.group;

    this.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
      let img = p.img;

      if (!img) {
        p.img = img = this.renderer.image('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Check-icon.png', -9999, 0, 15, 15).attr({
          zIndex: 10
        }).add();
      }

      const bbox = p.legendSymbol.getBBox();
      const x = p.legendGroup.translateX + tx;
      const y = p.legendGroup.translateY + ty;

      img.attr({
        x: x,
        y: y
      });
    });
  }
```

on load/redraw draw ticks

```
 chart: {
    events: {
      load: drawTicks,
      redraw: drawTicks
    }
  },
```

on legendItemClick change the img's visibility

```
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    point: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
          this.img.attr({
            visibility: !this.visible ? 'visibile' : 'hidden'
          });
        }
      }
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/3348yjrq/